# Delete SQL query in Access not working as expected

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table1 (PR_NOTES) where I'm trying to delete all records not found on table2 (DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN). I've tried several methods and this code is the closest (at least is not showing errors) that I've gotten to what I want:

```
DELETE *
FROM PR_NOTES
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BANFN, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.EKGRP, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.FRGZU, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.MENGE, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BSMNG, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.LOEKZ, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.EBAKZ, 
DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.PSTYP

FROM (DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN 
LEFT JOIN PR_NOTES
ON DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BANFN = PR_NOTES.BANFN));
```

To test this code, I created a fake record that I know is not found in table2:
[image]

The problem, is no record is ever deleted:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Error parenthesis hier?! `FROM (DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN LEFT JOIN PR_NOTES` .

Comment: Took them out (FROM DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN LEFT JOIN PR_NOTES
ON DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BANFN = PR_NOTES.BANFN...) and unfortunately did not make a difference.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference yet ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is like this.

```
DELETE FROM PR_NOTES
WHERE PR_NOTES.BANFN NOT IN (SELECT DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BANFN FROM DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN)
```

I am selecting all of the `BANFN` from `DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN` and I'm telling `PR_NOTES` to delete records that are not on the list. So if `PR_NOTES.BANFN` is not in `DW_ECC_SAP_EBAN.BANFN` then it will get deleted from `PR_NOTES`

Comment: With this query I'm getting an error " 'AggregateType' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long". I'm working with Access SQL.

Comment: NVM, it works. I created a new query from scratch. Access for some reason keeps some sort of logic in the background that messes up the queries if you happen to modify them...